# AutoCompleteTextView detect if user choosed suggestion

Tags: android, android-adapter

I only wan't the user to be able to click on a button if they have pressed a suggestion from my autocompleteTextview.

To accomplish this, i implemented an onKeyListener im my adapter and removed the tag which was set by the adapter if you pressed a suggestion. Then i checked if there was tag.

But the onKeyListener does not seem to remove the tag properly:

```
public class StopCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    public StopCursorAdapter(final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView, Context context, Cursor c){
        super(context, c);
        this.context = context;
        this.autoCompleteTextView = autoCompleteTextView;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        this.autoCompleteTextView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                StopCursorAdapter.this.autoCompleteTextView.setTag(null);
                Log.d("cursor", "Removed tag");
                Log.d("cursor", String.valueOf(StopCursorAdapter.this.autoCompleteTextView.getTag() == null));
                Log.d("cursor", String.valueOf(autoCompleteTextView.getTag() == null));         
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, null);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

        txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt1.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        txt2.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor){
        autoCompleteTextView.setTag(new Stop(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor
                .getString(3)));
        return cursor.getString(2);// + ", " + cursor.getString(3);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint){
        Database.getInstance().ensureLoaded(context);
        String filter = "";
        if(constraint == null){
            filter = "";
        }else{
            filter = constraint.toString();
        }
        Cursor cursor = Database.getInstance().getStopsCursor(filter);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your code:

- `setTag(new Stop(...))` is called from the adapter's `convertToString()` method which will be called by the AutoCompleteTextView when it is building the selection list (for each row in the cursor) and also when it is performing the completion. I don't think this is what you want.
- `setTag(null)` is called from the listener's `OnKey()` method which will be called when the user tap on the keyboard keys. I also don't think this is correct.

I think the correct code should be something similar to this instead:

```
    // set tag to non-null when key is pressed
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            autoCompleteTextView.setTag(new Stop());
            return false;
        }
    });

    // set tag to null when an item is tapped
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View v, int pos, long id) {
            autoCompleteTextView.setTag(null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the setOnClickListner method of the auto complete text view. item selected listener will fire when the list item gains focus & not on click(selection) of the item.

```
//set on click listener on the auto complete text view
autoField.setOnItemClickListener(autoItemSelectedListner);
```

and then,

```
private OnItemClickListener autoItemSelectedListner = new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        //extract selected
        selected = adapter.getItem(arg2);
    }
};
```

I hope this helps..

Answer (score -3):

Hmm it don't understand why you are using the tag. Perhaps I am missing a constraint.
Otherwise, I think this is what you are going after:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @override
  void public onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     makeSpecialButtonAvailable();
  }
  @override
  void public onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    //ignore
  }


});
```

Comment: I also have auto complete textview in my app and I implemented the same thing that you did here but on Selecting item the onItemSelected event is not get called. Do you have any idea why the method is not invoked?