# How to put a custom button into a search suggestions menu?

Tags: android, search-suggestion, search-box, google-books

I searched on the web but found no help regarding this. I would like to put a custom "Advanced Search" button into search suggestions that would guide the user to another activity/fragment. I have a screenshot of it implemented in Google Books app:
[Google books example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxXe4.jpg)

Does anybody know how to implement it?

Comment: As stated this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  You need to try something yourself and then if you get stuck show what you have already tried and be specific about what you need help with.  See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a view below the search bar and just change the visibility.

Another way would be to use an AutoCompleteTextView:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html
then use something like this to check which was chosen:
[AutoCompleteTextView detect if user choosed suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135155/autocompletetextview-detect-if-user-choosed-suggestion)

Otherwise, adding a menu button on the side would be a nice alternative.